# Wordpress: Gravity Forms: Adding more email notifications, based on input changing

Tags: php, forms, wordpress, email, plugins

I've added a hidden status field to my forms in gravity forms so I can keep track of where my customer's order is once they fill out my form.

What I need is: when I change that field in the dashboard to a new status I want gravity forms/wordpress to send a new email to that person, based on a new template I'm able to make.

Ex Flow:

1. User fills out form (they already get 1 email notification, comes with gravity forms)
2. I change the status in the dashboard by editing the entry
   (Next is new)
3. Wordpress/Gravity auto emails a new email to that user (based on a template I'm able to edit, just like the first email notification)

and so on with more status changes...

Thanks for any help possible! :)

Answer (score 2):

I've now accomplished this by adding conditional shortcodes to the email notifications and changing the primary content of the email in my template.

Documentation was found here:
http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Shortcodes#Conditional_Shortcode